# How to delete case properties from an existing case in CommCare

Tags: commcare

If I want to delete case properties from an existing case, can I do an excel upload and have the case properties be blank? Will that delete the case properties?

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove a case property completely but you can set it to a blank value or a value which indicates that it has not been set such as '**unset**'.